# SQL Query to split shipping cost over multiple items / rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, split

I am trying to create a query that will allow me to split a single figure over multiple rows.

For example, purchase order x may have 15 items allocated to it.  Shipping cost is, say, 9.95.  How can I calculate 1/15th of 9.95 and then update the cost price of the stock with 1/15th of the shipping cost?

Therefore the cost price of the item would increase from 4.50 to 5.16 (4.50 + 0.66).

Comment: Can you provide a sample table that you might use to hold this data?

Comment: Here you go...

[Purchase Order] POID, CustID, PODate, Supplier
[POStock] LinkID, PONo, StockCode, PurchasePrice

I'd like to update Purchase price with a share of the delivery cost.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?  sql server, oracle, mysql?

Comment: You should consider weighting your average by product weight (if you have that information stored and these are tangible products) or by product cost.  If row 1 of your PO is for 20 items worth 20 lbs or 20.00 USD each, it should receive more of the shipping price than row 2 for 20 different items worth 2 lbs or 2.00 USD each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a product table and updated the shipping price of items. 
Hope that's what you are looking for.

```
INSERT INTO [TravelAgentDB].[dbo].[Product]
           ([ID]
           ,[Name]
           ,[Price]
           ,[shippingPrice])
     VALUES
          (1,'Nexus 7' , 250 , 20),
          (2,'Nexus 7 case' , 50 , 20),
          (3,'Nexus 7 headphone' , 20 , 20)
GO


select * from product
Declare @itemsCount int
Select @itemsCount = count(*) From product where id in (1,2,3)
Declare @totalShippingPrice Decimal(18,2) = 9.95
Declare @shippingPriceperItem Decimal(18,2) = @totalShippingPrice / @itemsCount

Update Product 
set [shippingPrice] = @shippingPriceperItem
Where id in (1,2,3)
select * from product
```

Comment: Thanks Sayed, I have streamlined it all into one SQL Statement as follows:  

UPDATE [STOCK - DETAIL] set CostPrice = CostPrice + round((9.00 / (select count(*) from [STOCK - DETAIL] where PONo = 2971)),2) where PONo = 2971

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for SQL Server:

```
update  ol
set     price = price + 5.0 / ol.LineCount
from    [Order] o
join    (
        select  *
        ,       count(*) over () as LineCount
        from    OrderLine
        ) ol
on      o.ID = ol.OrderID
where   o.OrderNr = 'Ord1';
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0c0a/5/0)

If you're using another DBMS, please update your post!